# Asynchronous communication with JMS

Tags: java, jms

We are using in some project WebSockets for asynchronous communication between Java client and Java server, but we have to replace it with something less modern (we cannot use Websphere liberty profile and it must run on Websphere). Connection can be made only form client to server, not reversely and it should be HTTP(s) as it has to traverse a reverse proxy. Is it possible to use JMS to push messages to client in this situation? (we tried atmosphere-wasync as well but rejected it due to instability).

Comment: JMS solves your problem as described. But make sure that in order to use JMS you need a Message Broker and a subscriber that will consume those messages. If you have those, then go.

Comment: Should embedded hornetq server in spring boot do the job?

Comment: No it is not, I said no Liberty profile available.

Comment: Not sure why it needs to be HTTP, can you use a message acknowledgement to send something back to the client after the server does whatever work it needs to?